# table - absolute positioning (simple question)

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem. I've got table like this

```
 <table border="1">
        <tr style="position:relative;">
            <td>
                  <a href="link.php?l">Click here to redirect yourself</a>
                  <span onclick="ajax_redir();" style="position:absolute;right:5px;">
                       AJAX
                  </span>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
```

my problem is that AJAX is placed in the right corner of my screen. What am I doing wrong?
(I am trying to make AJAX text in corner of actual 
`<td></td>`)

demo of my problem http://jsfiddle.net/ehtwW/

Comment: AJAX will be in the td. Check the borders for the td. How's your text-align?

Comment: @genesis here's what I've got so far, http://jsfiddle.net/LaGZM/.

Comment: Right. But no change when I delete/change that

Comment: @genesis here's the Mozilla docs on positioning elements, by the way, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position

Comment: @genesis what do you mean when you delete/change it?  What are you deleting/changing?

Comment: @Keoki Zee: seocond. I'll show you mine

Comment: Look, this is the problem http://jsfiddle.net/ehtwW/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually kind of strange, but it seems that if you wrap all the contents of the `td` in a `div` it will work.

Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Gm5fg/1/

Comment: so my structure should work? Thanks for hint! I will accept you in a minute

Answer (score 2):

The TD has to be relatively positioned. For the TR it is not necessary:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td style="position:relative;">
              <a href="link.php?l">Click here to redirect yourself</a>
              <span onclick="ajax_redir();" style="position:absolute;right:5px;">
                   AJAX
              </span>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: @Luc sorry, a little late to the party, that's already been tried...see http://jsfiddle.net/LaGZM/1/.

Comment: I've tested my answer on IE before posting it.In most cases if some css works in IE it also works (even better) in other browsers. Now if I have to test every css-related answer on many browsers How can I come up with an answer as fast as @iuliux did?

Comment: @genesis Thanks, that's nice of you!